# Can't Bribe Ultima Weapon?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I'm on the PS3 version of Final Fantasy X Remastered, and I cannot bribe Ultima Weapon T.T

When I bribe him it pops up the "Immune" response.

I've tried with the North American bribe of 1,400,000 and the International bribe of 1,999,980, Ultima Weapon just keeps saying "Immune".

Is this a bug?

Comment: I hope you saved before!

Comment: @frank lol of course, but after 3 tries, I gave up, I still have the before save. I was just hoping someone out there had help for me.

Comment: I recall there being...two? types of Ultima Weapons; the boss at the end of the Omega Ruins, and the regular mob you run into getting to him.  Could it be that the one you're trying to bribe is the boss?

Comment: @Frank Uuuugh... you are exactly right. I was trying to bribe *Omega* and I don't have a save before Ultima. Gonna make for a lot more grinding T.T What are the policies of Arcade questions, should I delete, or do you wanna make that an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: Your choice.  Arqade specializes in setting straight such misunderstandings, so an answer might be useful to future readers.

Comment: @Frank Yeah hopefully this will prevent someone else from making my mistake. Would you mind posting your answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're getting Immune when trying to bribe a monster, chances are extremely good that you're trying to bribe a boss. Those are usually (with notable exceptions) immune to being bribed; gotta lay the smackdown honestly!

In your specific case, you're trying to bribe Omega, not Ultima.  Omega's immune to bribery, I'm afraid, so there's nothing for it but to just smash him as hard as you can.